# Meteor Accounts obtaining the SAML Response (Token / User after log in)

Tags: authentication, meteor, authorization, saml-2.0

i have a workin SAML logon with Meteor.accounts and MS Azure. I am using this https://github.com/steffow/meteor-accounts-saml library for SAML which is derived from https://github.com/bergie/passport-saml

The procedure goes like this:

1. Click saml login -> popup appears
2. Enter user/pw data in popup -> popup closes without error
3. Logged in success

So now i want to get the SAML Token for further processing (or at least the information about the logged in user which meteor has taken from the IDP).

Since i dont have a clue where the SAML Token is stored by Meteor or can be fetched in the code, can someone help me getting the SAML Response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably solved by now but here it goes..
According to the code the saml response is retrieved in "saml_server.js" at row 70 and the token should be in there also (loginRequest.credentialToken)
loginResult should be fairly easy to save into the Meteor.users collection

```
  var loginResult = Accounts.saml.retrieveCredential(loginRequest.credentialToken);
  var email = loginResult.profile.email;
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne({username: email});

  if (!user) {
    Accounts.createUser({
      "username": email,
      "profile": StufffromloginResult
    });
  } else {
    Meteor.users.update(
    {
      "username": email
    },
    { "$set": {
          "profile": StufffromloginResult,
        }
    });
  }
```

And retrieved with:

```
Meteor.user().profile
```

Comment: Ah yes i already solved this a while ago, but forgot to update.